# Forcing the environment to bash when executing shell command in C++

Tags: c++, linux, bash, shell

I'm creating an application in C++ that can execute some commands shell to get informations about the system. The problem occurs when I use in my script code something like `[[ "$devname" == "bus/"* ]]&& continue;`, executing this command returns error, probably because when executing the sheel script the environment are in `dash` instead of `bash`. I tried to execute the command with `#!/usr/bin/env bash` but don't work. The full command is hardcoded inline and I'm avoiding the use of a shell script file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a command like this, say:

```
[[ "$devname" == "bus/"* ]] && hostname || echo "no"
```

You can run it this way:

```
bash -c '[[ "$devname" == "bus/"* ]] && hostname || echo "no"'
```

So if you just build one string that contains the above, you can run it using `popen()` or whatever.  In C++ you'll have to escape the inner quotes if you use the above literally, so:

```
const char* command = "bash -c '[[ \"$devname\" == \"bus/\"* ]] && hostname || echo \"no\"'";
```

Comment: I use this solution because in my solution i'm using the popen, but only worked with the using of the command in hex format to avoid the use de scape character

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1) Explicitly set `SHELL` via `putenv()`:

```
putenv("SHELL=/bin/bash");
execl(...);
```

2) Explicitly execute `/bin/bash`, instead of relying on the hashbang:

```
execl("/bin/bash", script.c_str(), NULL);

// script is the script you're trying to execute.
```

Comment: I don't think that your solution (1) is supposed to work. Who should honor the `SHELL` variable? C++ won't necessarily do it (there is nothing in the standard, which would impose it), nor is it special for the program loader. If the script to be loaded, does not have a sheebang line, the default shell would be used (which is usuall `sh`).